# Changing minipage vertical alignment in mid-line?

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe,showcrop]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

aa
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{100pt}
Box 1
\end{minipage}}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{150pt}
\lipsum[11]
\end{minipage}}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{50pt}
 ..... Box 3
\end{minipage}}
zz

\end{document}
```

It results with the following output:

[image: a1]

All of the minipage boxes are top aligned.

Is it somehow possible to have the first and second minipage top-aligned (as they are) - but then have minipage 3 bottom-aligned to minipage 2 (and correspondingly, the last "zz" aligned to minipage 3)? Here is the desired output, composed in an image editor:

[image: a2]

I would prefer a solution where I don't have to wrap the minipages in another minipage/environment (or load another package, EDIT: *and that is because I eventually want to hook into a macro, which typesets a whole line [the "aa" to "zz"] parts - and allows me a hook for the middle; where I'd want to insert the miniboxes, and change the line alignment as shown*) - but lacking that, I'd be interested in hearing any approach which is applicable here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides measuring box heights and according manual placement you could use two `tabulars`. Compared to nested `minipages`, you do not have to specify any widths for the outer environment with this approach. Further packages are not required; however, if desirable e.g. for the "aa" and "zz" text parts, you could make use of advanced table features such as automatic-width `X` columns.

Proper bottom alignment of the two tables is sensitive to the insertion of a space, e.g. `[0pt]`, after the line breaks (alternatively, a rule may be used).

The tables insert some additional horizontal space in the current setting. This space can however be removed by placing `@{}` before/after each column in the column definitions and by removing the line break between the tables.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe,showcrop]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}
\begin{tabular}[b]{lll}
    aa 
    & \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{100pt}Box 1\end{minipage}} 
    & \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{150pt}\lipsum[11]\end{minipage}}
    \\[0pt]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{50pt}..... Box 3\end{minipage}}
    & zz
    \\[0pt]
\end{tabular}
\\\rule[\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{.5pt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for that @dgs - accept as I didn't even thing `tabular` would be applicable here! Unfortunately it still requires "wrapping" in an extern environment, including the "aa" and "zz" parts - and my ultimate intent is to hook into a different macro, which typesets a line with "aa" .. "zz", and I can only hook in the middle of the line, where I wanted to insert the miniboxes. But still, I think now I have enough to go further with this - many thanks again, and cheers!

Comment: but the baseline of box 1 is lower than either "aa" or the baseline of the first line in box 2, which doesn't look so good.  (that's also true in the original posting.)  otherwise, very nice.

Comment: Why do you use `[b]` in `\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}` while `tabular` is not floating?.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ah, thanks. The first `minipage` wasn't top-aligned in the original code, and I just copied/pasted it. I've updated the code, with rules added to show the alignment. @HarishKumar `tabular` takes its own position parameter. If you leave out any of the two `[b]`s, you'll notice that the result changes.

Answer (score 2):

Just a sidenote to [@dgs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58862/2595)' answer - note that what is holding the two fist boxes top-aligned, is the common `tabular` they are wrapped in; as soon as you try to break the `tabular`, the top alignment of the first two items stops (even if you keep the same arguments); that is, this:

```
\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}
\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}
    aa
    & \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{100pt}Box 1\end{minipage}}
    \\[0pt]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[b]{l}
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{150pt}\lipsum[11]\end{minipage}}
    \\[0pt]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{50pt}..... Box 3\end{minipage}}
    & zz
    \\[0pt]
\end{tabular}
\\\rule[\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{.5pt}
```

... results with this:

[image: a1.png]

... even if the three `tabular`s are `[b]`ottom aligned (*like the two `tabular`s in the answer were*); - and the three `minipage`s are aligned `[t]`, `[t]`, `[b]` (*also like in the answer*).

However, by accident, I also finally realized what I can use to "lift" the items in the first `tabular`; this is not necessarily trivial, because `\vspace`, `\vskip` or `\rule` (*negative height rules are not drawn at all!*) cannot be applied; however, as this snippet shows:

```
\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}
\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}
    % \vspace{-50pt}    % pushes down, doesn't "lift"
    % \vspace*{-50pt}   % pushes down, doesn't "lift"
    % \vskip -50pt      % ! Missing } inserted.
    % \vskip -50pt      % ! Missing } inserted.
    % \rule{4pt}{-60pt} % isn't drawn at all when negative
    aa \raisebox{-50pt}{b} \rule{4pt}{60pt}
    & \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{100pt}Box 1\end{minipage}}
    \\[0pt]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[b]{l}
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{150pt}\lipsum[11]\end{minipage}}
    \\[0pt]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{50pt}..... Box 3\end{minipage}}
    & zz
    \\[0pt]
\end{tabular}
\\\rule[\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{.5pt}
```

... it is `\raisebox` with a negative "raise distance" that can be used for this purpose *<sub>(sidenote: I looked at the definition of `\raisebox` in latex.ltx, and it seems that all it does is calculate some lengths, and apply them to the "currently selected" box ?!)</sub>*. Notice how the "`b`" acts as a bottom anchor now, taking up the "bottom" space relative to the environment:

[image: a2.png]

So, all that is left now is to measure the height of the `minipage`, and "raise" negatively by approx the same amount, and thereby "lift up" contents from the bottom of the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe,showcrop]{geometry}
\usepackage{trace}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newlength{\miniheight}

% save long minipage for tabular 2 into a box,
% so we can measure its height:
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox} %
  \begin{minipage}[t]{150pt}\lipsum[11]\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox} %

% note \baselineskip dissapears (is 0) in tabular!
% so save the default \baselineskip in
% another variable:
\typeout{\the\baselineskip} %
\newlength{\oldbaselineskip}
\setlength{\oldbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}
\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}
    % \vspace{-50pt}    % pushes down, doesn't "lift"
    % \vspace*{-50pt}   % pushes down, doesn't "lift"
    % \vskip -50pt      % ! Missing } inserted.
    % \vskip -50pt      % ! Missing } inserted.
    % \rule{4pt}{-60pt} % isn't drawn - is negative
    % note: correct height is ht + dp; not just ht!
    % +1em matches the {M} - 1.12\oldbaselineskip is manually tuned
    \settoheight{\miniheight}{\usebox\mybox} %
    \setlength{\miniheight}{\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox+1em-1.12\oldbaselineskip} %
    \typeout{\the\miniheight, \the\baselineskip} %
    aa \raisebox{-\miniheight}{M} \rule{4pt}{60pt}
    & \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{100pt}Box 1\end{minipage}}
    \\[0pt]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[b]{l}
    \fbox{\usebox\mybox}
    \\[0pt]
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}
    \fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{50pt}..... Box 3\end{minipage}}
    & zz
    \\[0pt]
\end{tabular}
\\\rule[\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{.5pt}

\end{document}
```

Note here:

- You must save the long minipage in a box to measure its height
- The actual height is `ht`+`dp` (not just `ht`) of the saved box
- You must use the package `calc`, to use `+` as addition operator in the `\setlength{\miniheight}...` stanza
- You must save the default `\baselineskip` - since it disappears within the `tabular` environment
- I used the character `M` there as anchor, so I could adjust to `1em` for the displacement height; however additional `-1.12\oldbaselineskip`, which I found manually (by trial and error)
- The `\raisebox` that does the shifting is inside a `\tabular` - but outside of a `\minipage`

... and finally that code results with this:

[image: a3.png]

How applicable this is to other similar contexts, I cannot tell as of yet `:)` Cheers!