# Changing vertical alignment of items in middle of line (for ToC entry)

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking, vertical-alignment

Well, I'm really starting to hate LaTeX sometimes - mostly because you can't really learn one thing, and have it applied everywhere else you wanted `:/`

For instance, I asked the question [Changing minipage vertical alignment in mid-line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58854/changing-minipage-vertical-alignment-in-mid-line), which got an answer that works in that context - but which I simply cannot apply in this context now, even if I have the same problem.

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% like definition for \phantomsection, but for part
% "Re: documentation for \phantomsection"
% http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2006-01/msg01612.html
\makeatletter
\def\phantompart{%
 \stepcounter{part}%
 \xdef\@currentHref{part.\thepart}%
 \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend}%
}
\makeatother

% tocloft custom TOC entry format:
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{ \fbox{ Entry } }
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\fboxsep=0pt % for framebox


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\phantompart %
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\contentsline{part}{%
    \thepart\hspace{1em}\ignorespaces %
      \fbox{ %
      A Short Entry %
      } %
  } %
  { \fbox{ \thepage } }
  { \fbox{ part.\thepart } }% fbox doesn't show!
} %

\phantompart %
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\contentsline{part}{%
    \thepart\hspace{1em}\ignorespaces %
      \fbox{ %
      \protect\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} %
        \textbf{A longer entry here...} \\ %
        Maybe something more written in this entry here, %
        just to show as an illustration ... %
      \protect\end{minipage} %
      } %
  } %
  { \fbox{ \thepage } }
  { \fbox{ part.\thepart } }% fbox doesn't show!
} %

\phantompart %
\addtocontents{toc}{%           % tocloft: this adds to toc, but NOT bookmark!:
  \protect\contentsline{part}{%
    \thepart\hspace{1em}\ignorespaces %
      \fbox{ %
      \protect\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} %
        \textbf{Another longer entry here...} \\ %
        Still, some more content entered here; %
        just to show as an illustration ... %
      \protect\end{minipage} %
      } %
  } %
  { \fbox{ \thepage } }
  { \fbox{ part.\thepart } }% fbox doesn't show!
} %



\vspace{0.2\textheight}
Some extra text...


\end{document}
```

The output of this example is as such:

[image: a.png]

Apparently, the entries in the table of contents are typeset as "one line", the `minipage`s being treated as characters - and all "characters" being centrally vertically aligned.

What I want is the same as in the [initial question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58854/changing-minipage-vertical-alignment-in-mid-line): I want the "Entry" and the title (`minipage`) top-aligned - and the title (`minipage`) and the page number bottom aligned.

I guess this means introducing a "soft" line break of sorts - as an instruction only for change of vertical alignment: that subsequent words should be aligned to the bottom of the previous word (but without actually creating the extra baseline skip [and starting again to position the words from the left margin] as with a real, "hard" line break).

Composed in an image editor, the desired output would look like this:

[image: a1-edited.png]

... but I simply cannot see what changes can I make to the code to implement this. If we go as per the [initial question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58854/changing-minipage-vertical-alignment-in-mid-line) - where would I insert the `tabular` environments, to implement the "soft" line break?

If there is a package that addresses this, I'd love to hear about it; but otherwise I'd be more interested in hearing a "core" method to solve this.

Comment: You should have a look at the `titletoc` package (bundled with `titlesec` and sharing the manual): on page 14 there's precisely the example you want.

Comment: Many thanks, @egreg - indeed, page 14 does have that example (_note to self: but it's showed as `\texttt`, not as an image; look up "If you have seen tocs, the latter should be familiar to you..."_) ... However, now I'd have to change all my templates etc `:(` - so, I'd still be interested in hearing a Latex solution to the posting as stated (with `tocloft`); hopefully I learn more about vertical alignment of items on lines ... Cheers!

Comment: @egreg - this w. `titletoc` not trivial at all;  I have been trying to make something like that for hours now, and no dice; posted on [Understanding titletoc example (and vertical alignment on line)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59192/understanding-titletoc-example-and-vertical-alignment-on-line). Cheers!

Comment: And just wanted to say that I got to some sort of a (complicated) solution with `\titletoc`, posted [in this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59271/2595); however, since this question is about `\tocloft`, I hope it's OK to also keep it open, until an answer arrives for it...

Comment: When you add a `[t]` to your minipages, everything gets alined to the first line. I personally prefer that to having the page numbers aligned to the last line ... of course this is not the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please forgive my LaTeX-noobness, I started using it, recently.
Have you tried something like this?

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\textbf{A longer entry here...} \\
        Maybe something more written in this entry here, \\ 
        just to show as an illustration ...}
```

I mean, without using the mini-page? I don't recognize all the code you use between {part} and the minipage so, possibly, it won't work the way you want, but I just wanted to help.

Comment: I mean no offense, but this is (by admission) not really an answer.  People sometimes put this kind of response in a comment (which I think you need a few more rep points to do), but as a rule, if you know it doesn't work, you shouldn't post it.  This site is not a discussion forum.  Nonetheless, welcome, and please enjoy reading the other questions and answers, which will definitely teach you a lot.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @Aerxis - I haven't tried it, but I'm pretty sure it won't work for me (I can guess that all the lines will be bottom aligned - I want top/top/bottom alignment in the same line). I generally managed to fix that with a different package in [Understanding titletoc example (and vertical alignment on line)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59192/understanding-titletoc-example-and-vertical-alignment-on-line?lq=1) - but it is far from trivial. Cheers!